# Question about ASP.NET MVC routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have actions SomethingEditor, SomethingDelete, SomethingSave, SomethingAdd and i want set these routing: site/Something/Editor, site/Something/Delete, site/Something/Save etc

How i can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "site/Something/Editor", new { controller = "Something", action = "SomethingEditor" });
routes.MapRoute(null, "site/Something/Delete", new { controller = "Something", action = "SomethingDelete" });
routes.MapRoute(null, "site/Something/Save", new { controller = "Something", action = "SomethingSave" });
routes.MapRoute(null, "site/Something/Add", new { controller = "Something", action = "SomethingAdd" });
```

**UPDATE:**

I strongly recommend using a seperate controller for each entity with the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "site/{controller}/{action}");
```

Comment: Well. Can i just add prefix [something] to action? If i have many actions it's hard work.

Comment: Not out of the box atleast. Tt might be possible with a custom httphandler but i strongly recommend using a seperate controller for each entity.